# JS RegExp catch words not followed by bracket

Tags: javascript, regex, matching

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression to match words that are not the beginning of a function.
So it should match everything, that is not followed by an opening bracket.

The "something" following the text should also not be put into the `[0]`-element of the result. So for a string of `test)`, the closing `)` should not be part of the matching group, which is why something like `^([a-zA-Z][\w-]*)(\s|$|\|,))` doesn't work.

An additional problem is, that the function name may contain a dash (hence the `[\w-]*`).

My first attempt:
`new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z][\w-]*)(?!\()/)`

This will match everything but the last character from the word, so `tes` from `test(`.

The next attempt was: `new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z][\w-]*)(?!\()\b/)`.

This will not match something like `test(` but will match `get-` from `get-border(`, because the `-` is a word breaking character.

I guess what I would need is "`\b` that is not a `-`", but not capturing it?

A few examples to maybe make clearer what I'm trying to accomplish:

- `foo(` -> `null`
- `arg)` -> `arg`
- `foo-bar(` -> `null`
- `arg` -> `arg`

The motivation for this problem: I want to split a text like `foo(bar(argument))` into a list of tokens: `['foo(', 'bar(', 'argument', ')', ')']`, given the regular expressions `FUNCTION_START`, `ARGUMENT` (< problem), `FUNCTION_END`.

Pseuo-Code:

```
while (line.length > 0) {
  regExp.some(r => {
    const match = line.match(r);
    if (match) {
      tokens.push(...);
      line = line.replace(r, '').trim();

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });
}
```

Which should not depend on the order of the regular expressions.

Comment: Do you mean `^[a-z]+(?=\)|$)` ? See [here](https://regex101.com/r/KmsZjs/1/)

Comment: How about `"foo(bar(argument))".match(/[a-zA-Z][\w-]*\(|[a-zA-Z][\w-]*(?=\))|\)/g`)?

Comment: I would suggest adding a `\b` and even reject when some optional spaces occur before the opening parenthesis: [`^([a-zA-Z][\w-]*)\b(?!\s*\()`](https://regex101.com/r/jxeW2L/1) . Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you @UnbearableLightness - the positive lookahead is a smart idea! Seems to pass all my current test-cases.

Comment: @Cabadath You are welcome, happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?=\)|$)
```

- `^` Assert beginning of line.
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Alphabetic characters, lower and upper case, one or more.
- `(?=\)|$)` Positive lookahead, match either a closing bracket `)` or end of line `$`.

You can test the regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/KmsZjs/2/).

Comment: I made some small adaptions, since the `[a-zA-Z]` an also contain numbers, underscores and dashes in my case. Also it can be succeeded by any whitespace or a comma. The final RegExp I'm currently using looks like this: `/^([a-zA-Z][\w-]*)(?=\)|,|\s|$)/`. But honestly, the entire "trick" behind it is using the positive lookahead (instead of a negative one).